# Chatbot Python Socket Programming

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I have a Server and Client script running on 2 different machines. I am creating a chat bot where the client and server can receive each others message and when "q" is typed on the client, the client terminates. Similarly when "q" is typed on the server, the server terminates too.

I do see the TCP connections taking place when client and server scripts are started

However, whatever I am sending from the client is not being received by the server and vice versa. Is there something wrong with the code logic?

Also, when I type "q" on the server end, it says "NameError: name 'q' is not defined". However, q is just a plain input string here.

Server Code

```
from socket import *
server_port = 7000
server_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('',server_port))
server_socket.listen(10)
print ("Welcome: The server is now ready to receive")
connection_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
while True:
  sentence = connection_socket.recv(2048).decode()
  print('>> ',sentence)
  message = input(">> ")
  #connection_socket.send(message.encode())
  if(message == "q"):
    message = "Server Side Termination"
    print("Server is terminating from this end")
    connection_socket.send(message.encode())
    #print("Server Close?")
    #new_message = input(">>> ")
    #if(new_message == 'q'):
    connection_socket.close()
  else:
    connection_socket.send(message.encode())
```

Client Code

```
from socket import *
server_name = '10.1.1.1'
server_port = 7000
client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((server_name,server_port))

while True:
  sentence = input(">> ")
  
  if(sentence == 'q'):
    sentence = "Client Side Termination"
    print("Client is terminating from this end")
    client_socket.send(sentence.encode())
    client_socket.close()
    break
  else:
    client_socket.send(sentence.encode())
  
  message = client_socket.recv(2048)
  
  print (">> ", message.decode())
```

***UPDATE***

Following is the error on the server side

```
user$ python s.py
Welcome: The server is now ready to receive
('>> ', u'')
>> hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s.py", line 14, in <module>
    message = input(">> ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hi' is not defined
```

Following is the error on the client side

```
user$ python c.py 
>> hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c.py", line 9, in <module>
    sentence = input(">> ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hi' is not defined
```

Comment: When I run your code both client and server send and receive data.

Comment: Are you running both client and server on the same host? Like using server as the local host? Also, does entering q on the server not cause any issues or traceback?

Comment: I have updated the thread with my error